# Should the doctor-octopus tag refer to both Otto and Olivia Octavius?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [doctor-octopus](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/doctor-octopus) tag wiki says it is supposed to be used to refer to the character of Doctor Octopus (Doc Ock for short). However, in various Marvel titles, Doctor Octopus has been both Otto Octavius *and* Olivia Octavius, and possibly other people in alternate universes.

Should the tag be used to refer to both of them or just Otto?

Comment: Third option, do we need a tag for him/her at all?

Comment: @Valorum There's only two questions with the tag, it could easily be got rid of if we want.

Comment: @Valorum Fair enough

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Every version of Doctor Octopus is still Doctor Octopus

Marvel, and *especially* Spider-Man have a history of [different versions themselves](https://spiderman.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Spider-Man_Variations), even before [Spider-Verse](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Peter_Parker_(Earth-616)#Spider-Verse).

I think the tags for characters with alternate dimensions versions should share that tag with the 'main' version (in the case of Marvel, that's Earth-616)

The only exception I can think of, where we have where the multiverse counterpart is tagged differently is [miles-morales](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/miles-morales), which only has one question. It's not clear if we want to keep that tag, but I'm not opposed to it in principle. Miles Morales is a much more written about character though, and probably deserves his own tag, separate from [spider-man](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spider-man).

In short, until there's a significant need we should keep just the one tag for all Doc Ocks.

Comment: Not every doc oc is a variant of Otto Octavius

Comment: @Valorum [she's](https://spiderman.fandom.com/wiki/Olivia_Octavius_(Earth-TRN700)) on this [list](https://spiderman.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Doctor_Octopus_Variations). That's good enough for me in this instance. But if you find a Doc Oc, that's not a version of Otto Octavius, that has been written enough about then please do create that tag.

Comment: Dr. Carolyn Trainer dons the octopus suit and goes around calling herself Doctor Octopus for a while, before settling on Lady Octopus; https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5C4L.png. Note that she's a student of Otto's, not an alternative version of him

Comment: @valorum apologies for getting back late. If the story involves Otto or relates to him (which it would for a lot of her stories) tag it as such, otherwise you don't need to. I wouldn't remove the tag from a Lady Octopus question though because of how closely they're related.